# JPA + Hibernate StoredProcedure with TableType

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa-2.1

I am trying to invoke Stored Procedure using hibernate/JPA. SP will have REF_CURSOR output & custome Table type named "t_tbl_type".

```
  PROCEDURE get_details (po_user       OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    po_cd    out t_tbl_type,
    po_number   out t_tbl_type,
                               pi_userid        in     VARCHAR2,
                               pi_location   in    VARCHAR2);


        StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("PKG.GET_DETAILS")
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("PI_USERID", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("PI_LOCATION", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("PO_USER", void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("po_cd", Object.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("po_number", Object.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                .setParameter("PI_USERID", "1").setParameter("PI_LOCATION", "New");
try {
            query.execute();

// I am getting error here
            List userOutput = query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have tried to register custom type output as "Object.class", void.class. Still i am getting

> UnsupportedOperationException: Type
>   [org.hibernate.type.ObjectType@35c3d6e8] does support multi-parameter
>   value extraction

Please help me how to get register custom output parameter type & read its value.